# Why is my "add comment" button disabled?

Tags: support, comments

My "add comment" button is disabled and I am not able to add comments/give a quick answer to a question, why did this happen, and when will I get the button back?

Comment: i guess bcz of ur reputation

Comment: Actually, form beginning onwords it is visible but not now, and it is even visible for my own question,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: That is strange, you shouldn't (yet) be able to comment on other people's questions but you should be able to on your own question

Comment: So for example, on [this question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604864/how-to-get-datakey-value-when-row-double-clikc-radgrid) you can't comment?

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in?

Comment: @AlEverett I just checked, when not logged there's no "add comment" at all so that's not the case.

Comment: If you're looking at it on Meta, you only need 1 reputation to do so, while it needs 50 reputation on the main SO site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add comments to your own questions, and to the answers to your questions, but to comment everywhere requires 50 reputation, and you currently only have 8.

See the "[Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)" privilege for more information.